# Ghost voting prevention in US state legislative bodies

Tags: united-states, voting

**Context**

Ghost voting, in this context, is when legislators vote for bills on behalf of other members who aren't actually present. 
I am somewhat embarrassed to say that I never knew about this practice until I watched [*John Oliver*'s 2/14/16 show focusing on voter ID laws](https://grist.org/politics/john-oliver-explains-how-voter-fraud-is-a-problem-but-only-among-politicians/).
That was a while ago, but the recent events involving voting reminded me of this issue and I was curious whether anything had been done to solve this problem.
Unfortunately, my research of google results turned up no significant information on recent steps taken by legislative bodies to prevent these practices.

**Question**

Are there actual examples of steps taken to stop the practice of Ghost voting in any US state legislative body in recent years?

Comment: Compare to the Westminster practice of “pairing” for medical / childcare etc needs.

Comment: Would it be possible to include or link to more information about the "recent events involving voting" you are referencing? The only such events I can think of have to do with Midterm Elections, which does not seem relevant because the question is about legislators voting rather than citizens voting.

Comment: How is "ghost voting" any different from the very common practice of [proxy voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_voting)?

Comment: This question and the answers to it overlap heavily with this previous question, which differs mostly by not presuming that "ghost voting" is a bad thing that should be stopped (a proposition which this post does really nothing to justify). https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26303/are-there-countries-where-members-of-the-legislative-body-are-allowed-to-vote-re/26363#26363

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there countries where members of the legislative body are allowed to vote remotely?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26303/are-there-countries-where-members-of-the-legislative-body-are-allowed-to-vote-re)

Comment: @ohwilleke, Not a duplicate.  Where proxy voting is not legal, (and therefore *is* presumed to be a bad thing), the term *ghost voting* applies.    Proxies aren't always good -- some new development might happen during the proxy's tenure which the authorizing party could not delegate in advance, but the proxy votes by rote even though the expected conditions no longer applied.  There's faithless proxies.  And negligent authorizing parties, who might slack off and let the proxy decide everything.  ...

Comment: @ohwilleke, ... The proxy might decide badly, or even so well that the slacker authorizer would then gain an undue good reputation, would they later employ to rise to some undeserved position of great responsibility.  At worst it would be like an incompetent medical student who employed proxies to complete his assignments, so that the student graduates to become a credentialed charlatan.

Answer (score 1):

I think the practice you are referring to is also called [Proxy Voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_voting). (+1 to Mark.)

The U.S. Senate has made rule changes to limit it, as I remember.    I couldn't find a specific notice of the change, but [this report](http://congressionalresearch.com/RS22952/document.php) from congressional research service will provide details; likely [*more details than you can shake a stick at*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more-than-you-can-shake-a-stick-at).

Comment: *"Ghost voting"* would for the present question refer to *illegal* proxy voting.  Re *"The U.S. Senate has made rule changes to limit it..."*": this phrasing tends to imply it's *generally* legal for Senators to proxy vote, but (outside of committees) it is not legal.